# How to use wget with header in gitlab_ci build?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, wget

How can I use `wget` adding the `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` or any other header information during `gitlab_ci.yml` build?

```
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - wget --header='JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN' https://git.my-company.com/projects/1234/repository/files/file.txt?ref=master
```

Result:

```
Pipeline cannot be run.
jobs:build:before_script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep
```

Why? According to: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#troubleshooting the wget command with header information should work, in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `… before_script config should be a string or a nested array of strings …` indicates that the YAML syntax is not valid. Please use the `/-/ci/lint` page in your project to correct it.

For example, this should work (`script:` is also needed):

```sh
  before_script:
      - 'wget --header="JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://git.my-company.com/projects/1234/repository/files/file.txt?ref=master"'
  script:
    - …
```

Comment: So the problem here have been the missing **single-quotes** around the whole wget command.

Comment: Yes, because of the `'` or `"` you need to use for the `--header` value. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#use-special-characters-with-script for more details :-)